# How do I print core block or views block in node.html.twig?

Tags: 8, theming

I'm pretty new to D8, so this might be basic stuff, but I can't find any tutorial how to do it.

In Drupal 7 this is the code that outputs core block in node.tpl.php:

```
<?php $block = module_invoke('block', 'block_view', '10'); print render($block['content']); ?>
```

This works for Views:

```
<?php print views_embed_view('viewname','block_10'); ?>
```

How do I achieve this in Drupal 8?

Comment: entity_load('block', $id)->view()

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: Sorry, that was wrong. It should be entity_load('block', $id)->getPlugin()->build();

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Drupal 8, you don't need (and should not) render in PHP. The rendering is done as late as possible in Twig.

So put the build array of your view in a variable.

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $variables['view1'] = views_embed_view('view1', 'block_news');
}
```

And then render it with `{{ view1 }}`.

Twig will handle the necessary rendering for all kind of render arrays that are possible in Drupal.

You can use the same for a block. (See the comment from Ivan Jaros.)

```
$variables['block1'] = entity_load('block', $id)->getPlugin()->build();
```

The `build()` method gives you the build array of the entity and you can use `{{ block1 }}`.

Comment: I wonder how to get that $id for the entity_load()

Comment: `'block'` is a config entity and `$id` is the block config entity ID aka machine name. If you are looking for content, then use the entity `'block_content'`

Comment: How to output a view title this way?

Answer (score 1):

If you have **multiple blocks** you can make a new region, place them there and use the following code.

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_node(&$variables){
  $result = array();
  $blocks = \Drupal::entityManager()
            ->getStorage('block')
            ->loadByProperties(array('theme'  => 'THEMENAME', 
                                     'region' => 'YOUR_NEW_REGION'));

  foreach ($blocks as $key => $block) {
    if ($block->access('view')) {
      $result[$key] = entity_view($block, 'block');
    }
  }

  $variables['YOUR_NEW_VARIABLE'] = $result;
}
```

Then use `{{ YOUR_NEW_VARIABLE }}` in your template file.