# How to embed views in a particular custom block template

Tags: theming, 8

I have created a views block in D8 and thinking to embed it within a particular custom block template I created to override (e.g block--myblock.html.twig), I wonder how to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have found a way to do so from another [post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/186246/how-to-print-core-block-or-views-block-in-node-html-twig-drupal-8?rq=1), tested and it works ! So basically..

1) Create a new variable in **mytheme.theme** file located in your default theme folder.

```
function mytheme_preprocess_block(&$variables) {

  $variables['view1'] = views_embed_view('view_name', 'block_news');

}
```

*'block_news' is your views block's machine name actually.*

2) And then use this twig in your block template.

```
 {{ view1 }}
```