# Place block region in node template

Tags: 8, blocks, theming

I am trying to place a block region inside a news content type but it is not rendering.

node--news.html.twig:

```
<article{{ attributes }} class="portal-article">

  <h1 class="article-title">{{node.label}}</h1>

  <p class="article-date">{{ date }}</p>

  <div class="article-main-content">
    {{ content }}
  </div>

  <div class="article-sidebar">
      {{ page.article_sidebar }}
  </div>

</article>
```

How can I get the block to render inside of a node?

Comment: Blocks are not within the scope of nodes. You basically want to construct a page with something like [page_manager](https://drupal.org/project/page_manager).

Comment: This was definitely possible in Drupal 7. Possibly related, D8: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/186246/how-to-print-core-block-or-views-block-in-node-html-twig-drupal-8

Comment: No, it wasn't, not like this. As @mradcliffe said, if you want use blocks and regions like that, you need  something like page_manager/panels/panelizer (the last is afaik not ported yet and the others are in progress). Display suite is also an option and allows you to use layouts in node templates.

Comment: I should have clarified, in D7, you could do it with a preprocess function, create a variable and then render that in a node template. It looks like the same thing is possible with D8 with issue I linked to above.

Answer (score 9):

This is probably the solution, "Making region content available to node templates in Drupal 8": http://atendesigngroup.com/blog/making-region-content-available-node-templates-drupal-8

---

Replace “THEME” with your theme name below:

```
/**
* Implements hook_preprocess_node() for NODE document templates.
*/
function THEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  // Allowed view modes
  $view_mode = $variables['view_mode']; // Retrieve view mode
  $allowed_view_modes = ['full']; // Array of allowed view modes (for performance so as to not execute on unneeded nodes)

  // If view mode is in allowed view modes list, pass to THEME_add_regions_to_node()
  if(in_array($view_mode, $allowed_view_modes)) {
    // Allowed regions (for performance so as to not execute for unneeded region)
    $allowed_regions = ['primary_content'];
    THEME_add_regions_to_node($allowed_regions, $variables);
  }
}

/**
* THEME_add_regions_to_node
*/

function THEME_add_regions_to_node($allowed_regions, &$variables) {
  // Retrieve active theme
  $theme = \Drupal::theme()->getActiveTheme()->getName();

  // Retrieve theme regions
  $available_regions = system_region_list($theme, 'REGIONS_ALL');

  // Validate allowed regions with available regions
  $regions = array_intersect(array_keys($available_regions), $allowed_regions);

  // For each region
  foreach ($regions as $key => $region) {

    // Load region blocks
    $blocks = entity_load_multiple_by_properties('block', array('theme' => $theme, 'region' => $region));

    // Sort ‘em
    uasort($blocks, 'Drupal\block\Entity\Block::sort');

    // Capture viewable blocks and their settings to $build
    $build = array();
    foreach ($blocks as $key => $block) {
      if ($block->access('view')) {
        $build[$key] = entity_view($block, 'block');
      }
    }

    // Add build to region
    $variables[$region] = $build;
  }
}
```

After clearing caches, I can now print content specified in Drupal’s block layout using my node template files. For example, if I’ve specified primary_content in $allowed_regions, then I can access it via node--node_type.html.twig with:

```
{{ primary_content }}
```

Comment: This looks like a link only answer. Please include a relevant quote of it in your answer here ...

Comment: There is an error in the call to `system_region_list()`: The second argument is not a string, but an integer. Then, since the function is declared as `system_region_list($theme, $show = REGIONS_ALL)`, there is no need to use the second argument, if you are going to use its default value.

Comment: I done this add to my .theme and I can add drupal blocks into this custom region,but region template isn't applied or suggest.How do you do this ? 
I posted about that few time ago.thanks

Comment: It worked for me (also considering kiamlaluno comment). THANK YOU