# Express block in region template

Tags: hooks, theming

I have `region--footer-sustain.html.twig` which is expressed in templates via `{{page['footer_sustain']}}`.

Client wants some content moved into the CMS so I added to `theme_info.yml` these regions:

`sustain_footer_left                       : 'Sustain Footer Left Col'
 sustain_footer_middle                     : 'Sustain Footer Middle Col'
 sustain_footer_right                      : 'Sustain Footer Right Col'`

I added the HTML to new Custom Blocks and assigned the blocks to the regions in the same way I have all over the site but no output was expressed.

I tried `{{page['sustain_footer_left']}}` and spitballing tried `{{region['sustain_footer_middle']}}` and later `{{sustain_footer_right}}`

After reading [Place block region in node template](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/196902/place-block-region-in-node-template) I tried editing theme.theme with the following:

```
function theme_add_regions_to_node($allowed_regions, &$variables) {
  // Retrieve active theme
  $theme = \Drupal::theme()->getActiveTheme()->getName();

  // Retrieve theme regions
  $available_regions = system_region_list($theme, 'REGIONS_ALL');

  // Validate allowed regions with available regions
  $regions = array_intersect(array_keys($available_regions), $allowed_regions);

  // For each region
  foreach ($regions as $key => $region) {

    // Load region blocks
    $blocks = entity_load_multiple_by_properties('block', array('theme' => $theme, 'region' => $region));

    // Sort ‘em
    uasort($blocks, 'Drupal\block\Entity\Block::sort');

    // Capture viewable blocks and their settings to $build
    $build = array();
    foreach ($blocks as $key => $block) {
      if ($block->access('view')) {
        $build[$key] = entity_view($block, 'block');
      }
    }

    // Add build to region
    $variables[$region] = $build;
  }
}
```

And then called it like so:

```
function theme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {  
  $view_mode = $variables['view_mode']; // Retrieve view mode
  $allowed_view_modes = array('full'); // Array of allowed view modes (for performance so as to not execute on unneeded nodes)

  // If view mode is in allowed view modes list, pass to THEME_add_regions_to_node()
  if(in_array($view_mode, $allowed_view_modes)) {
    // Allowed regions (for performance so as to not execute for unneeded region)
    $allowed_regions = array('sustain_footer_left','sustain_footer_middle','sustain_footer_right');
    theme_add_regions_to_node($allowed_regions, $variables);
  }
}
```

Also tried commenting out the `if(in_array())` as a test.
Also tried doing same in `theme_preprocess_page()`.

**UPDATE**

Also tried

```
  $variables['sustain_footer_right'] = entity_load('block_content', 'sustainfooterrightcolumn')->getPlugin()->build(); 
 $block = \Drupal\block_content\Entity\BlockContent::load('sustainfooterrightcolumn');
 // $variables['sustain_footer_right'] = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('block_content')->view($block);
```

And also tried

```
 $custom_block = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('block_content')->load('96');
 $variables['sustain_footer_right'] = $custom_block->field_myfield->value;
```

AND ALSO TRIED

```
  $block = \Drupal\block\Entity\Block::load('sustainfooterrightcolumn');
  if ($block) {
  $variables['sustain_footer_right'] = \Drupal::entityManager()
          ->getViewBuilder('block')
          ->view($block);
  } else {
    $variables['sustain_footer_right'] = 'x';
  }
```

Also in twig tried all of these, and yes, cleared cache every time.

`{{sustain_footer_right}}
{{page.sustain_footer_right}}
{{page['sustain_footer_right']}}`

I get no errors but also no output.  How do I get the content of these blocks to be expressed in `region--footer-sustain.html.twig` ?

Comment: Did you clear the cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a new region to output blocks in does not require a whole lot of code other than the yaml definition you already have. From there, you just need to render the region in the page template:

```
{% if page.sustain_footer_right %}
  {{ page.sustain_footer_right }}
{% endif %}
```

If you make a custom region twig file, it needs to render also:

```
<div class="container">
  {{ content }}
</div>
```

Based on your region name, the twig template should be `region--sustain-footer-right.html.twig`.

This is all that is needed to render blocks in new regions. I would say eliminate all the custom code and starting from there.

Comment: Thank you- So originally I had functional region--footer-sustain.html.twig which is expressed in templates via {{page['footer_sustain']}}.  I need to make region--sustain-footer-right.html.twig and render in region--footer-sustain.html.twig via {{ page.sustain_footer_right }} ?

Comment: Yes it should be dot notation. But, you don't even need the custom region template - the system will use region.html.twig provided by core base theme.