# Template preview not working properly

Tags: 8, blocks, theming

I've got a huge problem with my template preview. For all of my post (page, article and so on), I have not the good region in my page.

My theme is extended Classy.

If I go to see the page (not from the preview), I have the good page. 
But if I want to see the preview of this page, I've got some missing region (I guess this is a region).

See my **page--post-type.html.twig**

```
        {% include '@theme/layout/header.html.twig' %}
    {% include '@theme/includes/page-head.html.twig' %}
    {% include '@theme/includes/page-breadcrumb.html.twig' %}
    {% include '@theme/includes/page-entry.html.twig' %}

    <section id="page-content">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row"> {{ some displayed data }}
    </div></div></section>
{% include '@theme/layout/footer.html.twig' %}
```

My included files a working (for both preview and view), but the preview isn't in this page is guess.

The last included block is this for the preview :

> BEGIN OUTPUT from 'themes/theme/templates/block/block.html.twig'

And for some reason, after I have this :

> BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/themes/classy/templates/content/node.html.twig'

if it helps, my .theme file :

```
    /**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_page_alter().
 */
function theme_theme_suggestions_page_alter(&$suggestions, $variables) {
//    $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
    if ($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node_preview')){
        $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node_preview');
//        if ($node instanceof \Drupal\node\NodeInterface) {
//            $suggestions[] = 'page__' . $node->bundle() . '_preview';
//            $suggestions[] = 'page__node_' . $node->bundle() . '_preview';
//        }

    } else {
        $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
        if ($node instanceof \Drupal\node\NodeInterface) {
            $suggestions[] = 'page__' . $node->bundle();
            $suggestions[] = 'page__node_' . $node->bundle();
        }
    }

//    dump($suggestions);

}
```

And I have also this function **alstef_preprocess_node()** which I took from this : [Place block region in node template](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/196902/place-block-region-in-node-template)

I've been stuck for hours, any help you be appreciated.

PS : I'm working on drupal 8 with a custom Theme (here called 'theme').

**EDIT :** I've just made a dump of my node, and the node is null is i'm on my page--post-type.html.twig or page--post-type-preview.html.twig with the preview (change thanks to suggestions)

Answer (score 1):

While previewing a node, the node parameter is not "upcasted" from an integer to a node object. But you can easily do this yourself in the preprocess function, just add those lines before:

```
  $router = \Drupal::routeMatch();
  $node = $router->getParameter('node');
  if (is_numeric($node)) {
    $node = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load($node);
  }
  //now you always have "real" node object (instanceOf Drupal\node\NodeInterface -> true), 
  //no matter if preview or normal viewing
```